# What is the most logical belief I can hold about the value of an unknown coin I lost at a Cafe?

Tags: belief

This is a real incidence. A couple of hours ago, I was sitting in a Cafe, and while fiddling with my wallet, two coins fell out of it. I picked one quickly, but the other one just rolled away below another table in the dark. I searched for it, but couldn't locate it. The currency that I have in my wallet is Euros. I know that the coin was either 1 Euro or 2 Euros. I have no more information about this. For example, I don't remember how many coins were there in my wallet etc. Now I want to have a best possible or logical guess at how much money I actually lost. Would assuming that I lost 1 Euro over 2 Euros be more logical or less? For either answer, what is the logical principle(s) that is at work?

Comment: if you truly have no other information then it's 50:50

Comment: An economist would calculate the expected value of the loss, which in this case is 0.5 * 1 + 0.5 * 2 = $1.5, assuming that there is no other information, so it's 50:50 as zero says.

Comment: It is worth as much as the next stray coin you find.

Comment: ... and a whole new branch of mathematics is born! I salute you sir/ma'am as the case may be.

Comment: This is a typical problem of probabilities, not philosophy. Should be closed.

Comment: @RodolfoAP You need to read some David Lewis, Ernest Adams or Dorothy Edgington. Eminent non-philosophers in your book, I take it?

Answer (score 1):

Its value was unknown to you. Value is relative. Also, some coins are very valuable, far more so than their suggested face value. No answers are addressing this. I thought this was philosophy

Answer (score 1):

The most logical belief is that you lost either one or two Euro. It is not logical to believe anything else, since you have said you have no other information to base that believe on.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most logical belief I can hold about the value of an unknown coin I lost at a Cafe?

Based on the information, you either lost 1 euro or 2 euros. It's 50/50. Literally, flip a coin and choose. This is a logical belief

But suppose the coin value matters. After all, losing two euros is worse than one. From a budget and financial risk standpoint the fiscally conservative choice is to assume you lost 2 euros. That way you avoid being overdrawn at the bank. This is another logical belief.

Logical belief depends on context as well as probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Imagine a gun to your head that would go off telling you to pick between the two and that if you’re wrong you would get killed. Which would you pick?

I would wager on the one euro simply because I’m guessing it’s a coin that you more commonly hold than the two euro one.

Comment: two euros is larger and so more difficult to hold

Comment: True, I’m not European but makes sense

Comment: @thinkingman you are cheating - because the problem says you have no other information. So you have no real justification to assume that 1 euro is more commonly held. No other information means no other information. You have to play by the rules.

Comment: i suppose he is implicitly asserting there is always more information @Frank

Comment: My way of saying it is: if you can't decide something, flip a coin and, while it is in the air, you will know which side you want it to land on. No need for violence.